# Is there a better way to assign ID's for a large number of elements and buttons in HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var persist = false;
var persist1=false;

  $(".hover_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
    persist = !persist;
  })
  
  $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!persist)
    {
            $("#tab1default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
  $(".hover_btn1").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
    persist1 = !persist1;
  })
  $(".hover_btn1").mouseenter(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".hover_btn1").mouseleave(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!persist1)
    {
            $("#tab2default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#customTab a {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-dark:hover,
.btn.focus,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn.focus,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:hover,
.active>a .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.hover_btn {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hover_btn:hover {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="container" id="customTab">
      <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="collapse" id="test"><span class="hover_btn">Water</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="hover_btn1">soil</span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="hover_btn2">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default">
          <div class="flex ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade hover_btn3" id="tab2default">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I have multiple buttons and hovering functionality on those buttons and I have manually assigned ID's for both like "hover_btn", "hover_btn1" and the list goes on. Similarly for the button, the id is assigned like "tabl1default","tab2default" and so on. How can I implement it with a loop or some random generator so that I don't have to manually increment numbers all the time in both my html and JS code. Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ptaej51d/

Comment: You should probably consider using classes instead of ids for some features. Ids are unique and so should be used when you need to target a single element. Things like hovering buttons (i imagine will be the same for all) can be done usually with a class

Comment: @LelioFaieta i am already using classes for hovering

Comment: The snippet you have added to your question does not run. Can you add jQuery, CSS,... etc  -- the minimal necessary to make it run correctly?

Comment: @trincot i updated the code and added fiddle

Comment: @LelioFaieta could be. i am not sure about that. ? Could you look at my updated code?

Comment: The best way to use IDs in a situation like this, is probably not to use them in the first place. There are other ways to navigate around the DOM, than accessing elements directly by ID.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've posted my answer before you have updated your code, so it doesn't really refer to the code you have currently.

I don't think there is any way to loop in HTML, but you can always loop and create HTML elements from JavaScript.

You could create a template function that would create all your HTML elements to which you would pass your `hover_btn<n>` and `tab<n>default` attribute values from a `for` loop. Another function would set all event listeners. Since the HTML elements are created using JavaScript, all their data would also have to be stored in JavaScript (e.g. their `innerHTML`).

HTML:

```html
<ul
    id="navigation"
    class="nav"
    style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const
        // How many elements will be created
        count = 5,

         // Attribute value placeholders, where `~` is the placeholder for a number
        elements = [
            'hover_btn~',
            'tab~default',
            'persist~'
        ],

        // HTML for span elements in the order they appear in the DOM
        html = [
            'Wasser',
            'Sedimente',
            'Biologische<br>Proben</br>',
            'Luft',
            'Lebensmittel'
        ];

    // Functions
    const
        addHtmlElement = i => {
            // Create all elements
            var
                li = document.createElement('LI'),
                a = document.createElement('A'),
                span = document.createElement('SPAN');

            // Create an HTML structure
            document.getElementById('navigation').appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(a);
            a.appendChild(span);

            // Add all attributes
            a.setAttribute('href',`#${elements[1].replace(/\~/g,i + 1)}`);
            a.setAttribute('data-toggle','tab');

            // Replace value for `hover_btn~` number
            var hoverNum = (i > 0) ? i : '';
            span.setAttribute('class',elements[0].replace(/\~/g,hoverNum));

            // Set innerHTML for span
            span.innerHTML = html[i];

            // Add event listeners
            addEventListeners(hoverNum);
        },
        addEventListeners = hoverNum => {
            $(`.${elements[1]}${hoverNum}`).click(e => {
                e.stopPropagation();    
                eval(`persist${hoverNum} = !persist${hoverNum}`);
            });

            $(`.${elements[1]}${hoverNum}`).mouseenter(e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(`#tab${hoverNum ? 2 : 1}default`).removeClass('collapse').addClass('fade').addClass('in').addClass('active');
            });

            $(`.${elements[1]}${hoverNum}`).mouseleave(e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!persist) {
                    $(`#tab${hoverNum ? 2 : 1}default`).addClass('collapse').removeClass('fade').removeClass('in').removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        };

    // Add event listeners once
    $('#create_btn').on('click',() => {
        $('#create_tab').tab('show');
    });

    $('#create_btn').on('click',() => {
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show');
    });

    $('#login_btn').on('click',() => {
        $('#login_tab').tab('show');
    });

    // For loop
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) addHtmlElement(i);
});
```

Creating HTML DOM elements using JavaScript:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Setting attributes using JavaScript:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

---

This answer is based on your original code:

Original HTML:

```html
<ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn" >Wasser</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                    class="hover_btn1">Sedimente</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                    class="hover_btn2">Biologische<br>Proben</br>
                     </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab4default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn3">Luft</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab5default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="hover_btn4">Lebensmittel</span></a>
        </li>
```

Original JavaScript:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    var persist = false;
    var persist1=false;
    var persist2=false;
    var persist3=false;
    var persist4=false;
    $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create_tab').tab('show')
    })

    
    $('#login_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#login_tab').tab('show')
    })

     $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
    })

    $(".hover_btn").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    
        persist = !persist;
      })
      
      $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#tab1default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!persist)
        {
                $("#tab1default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
      $(".hover_btn1").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    
        persist1 = !persist1;
      })
      $(".hover_btn1").mouseenter(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#tab2default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".hover_btn1").mouseleave(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!persist1)
        {
                $("#tab2default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
 
      $(".hover_btn2").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    
        persist2 = !persist2;
      })
      $(".hover_btn2").mouseenter(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#tab2default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!persist2)
        {
                $("#tab2default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
      $(".hover_btn3").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    
        persist3 = !persist3;
      })
      $(".hover_btn3").mouseenter(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#tab2default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".hover_btn3").mouseleave(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!persist3)
        {
                $("#tab2default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
      $(".hover_btn4").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();    
        persist4 = !persist4;
      })
      $(".hover_btn4").mouseenter(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
            $("#tab2default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".hover_btn4").mouseleave(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!persist4)
        {
                $("#tab2default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
});
```

Note to your original code:
In programming, if you are copy/pasting, you are probably doing it wrong.